# Authentication attempt has failed when login Cas-server

Tags: java, spring-boot, single-sign-on, cas

I am using the documentation from the website https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cas-sso#cas-server-setup-user-config to set up Cas-server for my Spring Boot application. However, when I reached step 2.3, CAS Server User Configuration to configure the Cas server account for logging in, I encountered the following error like "Authentication attempt has failed". And the error message displayed on the command line is as follows:

```
2023-04-12 14:32:56,896 ERROR [org.apereo.cas.web.flow.executor.EncryptedTranscoder] - <Null input buffer>
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null input buffer
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2198) ~[?:?]
        at org.apereo.cas.util.cipher.BaseBinaryCipherExecutor.decode(BaseBinaryCipherExecutor.java:92) ~[cas-server-core-util-api-6.1.7.2.jar!/:6.1.7.2]
        at org.apereo.cas.util.cipher.BaseBinaryCipherExecutor.decode(BaseBinaryCipherExecutor.java:33) ~[cas-server-core-util-api-6.1.7.2.jar!/:6.1.7.2]
        at org.apereo.cas.util.crypto.CipherExecutor.decode(CipherExecutor.java:105) ~[cas-server-core-api-util-6.1.7.2.jar!/:6.1.7.2]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:279) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:499) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.0.RC1.jar!/:2.2.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy173.decode(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.executor.WebflowCipherBean.decrypt(WebflowCipherBean.java:35) ~[cas-server-core-webflow-api-6.1.7.2.jar!/:6.1.7.2]
        at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.executor.EncryptedTranscoder.decode(EncryptedTranscoder.java:103) ~[cas-server-core-webflow-api-6.1.7.2.jar!/:6.1.7.2]
        at org.apereo.cas.web.flow.executor.ClientFlowExecutionRepository.getFlowExecution(ClientFlowExecutionRepository.java:75) ~[cas-server-core-webflow-api-6.1.7.2.jar!/:6.1.7.2]
        at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:167) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.1.RELEASE]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:279) ~[spring-core-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:499) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.2.0.RC1.jar!/:2.2.0.RC1]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy210.resumeExecution(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:254) ~[spring-webflow-2.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:665) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:750) ~[javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar!/:4.0.1]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apereo.cas.web.support.AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationCredentialsThreadLocalBinderClearingFilter.java:28) ~[cas-server-core-web-api-6.1.7.2.jar!/:6.1.7.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apereo.cas.web.support.filters.RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.doFilter(RequestParameterPolicyEnforcementFilter.java:411) ~[cas-server-core-web-api-6.1.7.2.jar!/:6.1.7.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apereo.cas.web.support.filters.ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeadersEnforcementFilter.java:216) ~[cas-server-core-web-api-6.1.7.2.jar!/:6.1.7.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apereo.cas.web.support.filters.AddResponseHeadersFilter.doFilter(AddResponseHeadersFilter.java:67) ~[cas-server-core-web-api-6.1.7.2.jar!/:6.1.7.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:157) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apereo.cas.logging.web.ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.doFilter(ThreadContextMDCServletFilter.java:99) ~[cas-server-core-logging-6.1.7.2.jar!/:6.1.7.2]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apereo.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:66) ~[inspektr-common-1.8.6.GA.jar!/:1.8.6.GA]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-catalina-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-coyote-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-coyote-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-coyote-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-coyote-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-coyote-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar!/:9.0.37]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
2023-04-12 14:32:57,089 INFO [org.apereo.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN
```

I configured the cas.properties file in the directory E:\GIT_JAVA\cas-server\src\main\resources\etc\cas\config so
I use the following command to run the Cas server:

```
gradlew run -Dorg.gradle.java.home=%JAVA_HOME% -Pargs="-Dcas.standalone.configuration.directory=E:\GIT_JAVA\cas-server\src\main\resources\etc\cas\config"
```

What did I do wrong or need to fix? Can anyone help me?

Comment: I using cas-server-overlay 6.1

Answer (score 0):

The CAS server internally uses a state machine called the "webflow".

Given the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null input buffer` on the `org.apereo.cas.web.flow.executor.ClientFlowExecutionRepository.getFlowExecution`, I guess that the "execution" parameter in the login form is missing and thus is not posted when you submit your credentials. Can you check that?